# Set all products in Stock with custom message from quantity 0 and below

Tags: magento-1.9, stock, stock-status

I want to have all the products always in stock but if the quantity is 0 or below to show a custom message instead of "in stock".
Magento 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make sure that backorders are enabled (to allow qty below 0)

[image]

Then in your template just validate the qty and display the message:

```
<?php id($_product->getQty() <= 0): ?>
    <p>Some custom message</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```